# Trigonometric show that question

Tags: trigonometry

Show that:

$\sin (X) + \sin (Y) = 2 \sin (\frac{X+Y}2)\cos(\frac{X-Y}2)$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right lines.

LHS = $\sin X + \sin Y$

= $2\sin (X/2)\cos(X/2) + 2\sin(Y/2)\cos(Y/2)$

= $2 (\sin (X/2)\cos(X/2) + \sin (Y/2)\cos(Y/2))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the compound-angle formulae $\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B\pm\cos A\sin B$, from which we get $\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)=2\sin A\cos B$. Now take $A=\frac{X+Y}{2},\,B=\frac{X-Y}{2}$.